# Why число, not четло?

Tags: этимология

If it comes from PIE ***q̆etlom*** then the Russian reflex should be "четло". Why it is число then? A speculation may be that it came from ***q̆etˢtlom***, in this case it would become чесло.

What is the correct analysis?

Comment: PIE _q̆etˢtlom_ would give PS _čestlo_ but there is no T also in West Slavic languages (_číslo_ and Old Polish _czysło_). It may contain PS suffix _-slo_ as in весло from _veslo_ (_vez-slo_) and be connected with читать. Etymology of Latvian _[skaitīt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skait%C4%ABt)_ on Wiktionary seems to agree with this interpretation and suggests PIE root _skey-_.

Comment: @BartekChom oh no, the PIE root was q̆et and meant "fitting together", for instance, in a word for a pair q̆eta̯. It is a very ancient root reconstructed for proto-Eurasiatic as well where it would produce numerals for two. It is also a source for the word for four and the -q̆e clitic.

Answer (score 3):

In Proto-Slavic it was most likely četslo/čitslo. Then "t" just dropped down due to the rule of ascending sonority (закон восходящей звучности), one of the most basic phonological rules of Old East Slavic (or Old Russian, whatever you call it).

Exactly for the same reason we have "прясло" (was прѧтсло initially) and "ясли" (derived from *ēdsli-).

This happened in Proto-Slavic so actually there are some more non-obvious examples, when this particular changes was affected by some other phonetical mutations. For instance [pṓds](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/p%E1%B9%93ds) - the reconstructed Proto-Indo-European word for foot is something that gave us words "пехота" and "пеший" (first, ds -> s, then it morphed into x and ʂ).

Comment: So the PIE form was ***q̆etslom***?

Comment: @Anixx nope, that is something I'm not sure about, I'm not aware about the PIE reconstruction.